# Unescape unicode characters from a string

Tags: python, unicode

I have a string which contains unicode characters which looks like this,

> ```
> "u'type'` does not belong to `[u'item1', u'item2']"
> ```

How would I unescape the unicode parts?

So that it prints out,

> ```
> "'type' does not belong to ['item1', 'item2']"
> ```

Comment: Generally, I would expect that you'd be better off modifying the code which created the string ...

Comment: I agree but it's coming from JsonSchema so I dont have control over what's being returned

Comment: Just for clarification, should there be an apostrophe before item1 so that it is enclosed or do you want that removed? The way you are showing that it will print out is a little inconsistent. "Type" isn't enclosed by any apostrophe, "item1" has one apostrophe, and "item2" has 2 apostrophes

Comment: Thank you, I've made correction so that item1's enclosed in apostrophes.

Comment: Following my last comment, should "type" be enclosed in apostrophes also then?

Comment: actually, without the apostrophes should be fine as well as long as it doesn't look unicode anymore. Thanks!

Comment: Either should work! I've enclosed it in apostrophes to make it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the replace method for the string

```
stringToModify = "u'type' does not belong to [u'item1', u'item2']"

stringToModify.replace("u'","'")
```

Comment: What if the message was "u'stuff' does not belong to [u'fu2', u'wut']" ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. This is what I get: "'stuff' does not belong to ['fu2', 'wut']" Is that not what was asked for?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, if you specify `u'` then it won't match `u'fu2'` `you'll` would be a different story

Comment: Oops yes I missed the additional "'" (hard to read on a phone screen sorry)

Comment: Good call on "you'll", I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

What you show here is actually a byte string displaying the representation of three Unicode strings (all of them containing only ASCII characters FWIW).

If you cannot change the code producing this string your only solution is `re.sub()`.